# Unable to start Performance profiler in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

When I try to start Performance/Diagnostic profiler, I get following message in Diagnostic Hub output:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range. (HRESULT: 0x80070057)
'...' failed to launch

Exception of type 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.CollectionStartFailedHubException' was thrown.
```

There is also `No data is being collected yet. Start debugging to see diagnostic data.` message in Diagnostic Tools window.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with me was deleting Scratch directory while cleaning up computer. When I recreate this folder, everything started to work properly.

[image: Diagnostic Tools Property Pages screenshot]

Comment: How did you get this window up?

Comment: Also not working. How to open this window?

Comment: VS menu: "Debug->Windows->Diagnostic tools." A window shows which has "Select tools" dropdown. You need to select "Settings" from the dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

1. Debug -> Windows -> Show Diagnostic Tools

[image: Diagnostic Tools]

2. Select Settings from the Select Tools dropdown

[image: Diagnostic Tools Settings]

3. Make sure the path for the Scratch Directory is valid, or add one if missing
4. Re-launch the diagnostic tool